# Is having a Pre-Human society worth it?

Tags: ancient-history

I will not lie and say I am a published author, however, I have spent a fair bit of time on [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/) and know how to avoid pitfalls such as the Mary Sue. This is all to say that I wish to add an element to my story that I fear would elicit a groan out of anyone who enjoys reading stories as a hobby. The ancient society that died out hundreds (or thousands) of years ago.

The reason I think this might be okay is that I am not going to be using this fact of "history" as a crutch to give the heroes a MacGuffin when all seems lost. Nor will it be a static piece of background that gives a prophecy to a small rural farm village that has a shepherd go on a quest to kill the Evil Lord, looking at you here WoT... This pre-book time will be the source of the worlds strengths and will even feature explicitly in the book itself as I would be taking the readers back to show them why certain things are the way they are.

So with all that context done with I can give a more precise question. From the information I have given you, is it worth risking my audiences derision at picking such a common background, or is it unique enough to survive in this saturated market? If it is not a good choice I would like to ask why it is not a good choice.

Comment: It would depend you :) There are myths from all around the Globe, that the 9 Gods of old, tried various forms of Life. Ending each because of a short coming.  So the myth goes, Humans are at the end of their time and the final version will come.  What that next version is ..... well that is what Stories are made of.

Comment: This question is more about writing than worldbuilding.

Comment: @sphennings Well basically anything can be writing. But this is about building a world and what kind of pasts are worthwhile and which ones should be thrown off a cliff.

Comment: @sphennings: Not just about writing, it's couched in terms that probably only writers could understand.  What the heck's a "Mary Sue" or a "MacGuffin"?  (I presume it's not a typo for McMuffin :-))  And what the heck's wrong with having a pre-existing society as background?  Tolkien did ok with it, to name just one.

Comment: @jamesqf the problem is that you've got hundreds of people after Tolkien who've done it, some of them very well (e.g. Frank Herbert) and some not so well. It's been done *a lot* and so the trope is a bit tired. To the OP, I'd suggest throwing in tidbits about old civilizations which might "spice up" the story a bit, but please don't pull a [Celestine Prophecy](http://kenneth.moyle.ca/cp/) and don't let your entire plot hinge on it.

Comment: @jamesqf Wikipedia is your friend re. [Mary Sues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue) and [MacGuffins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)

Comment: This question is basically unanswerable now. Torment: Tides of Numenera had eight ancient civilizations in succession, with really good effect. And there are some horrible examples, too. It depends on the world you are building. And I think this question qualifies as *["there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*.

Comment: I think this question really belongs on Writing.Se

Comment: @errantlinguist: That's part of the point I was trying to make.  It's not so much the plot element as what the writer does with the element that makes the difference between a good story and a bad one.  3500 years or so after Homer, we're still ringing changes on "boy meets girl, and look at all the trouble it caused" :-)

Comment: @errantlinguist: Wikipedia might be my friend if I really wanted to know what those are.  The other point I was trying to make, though, is that it's really not a good idea, and IMHO thoughtlessly rude, to ask questions of a general audience that use words & concepts that aren't common outside a specialized field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not worth audiences derision to have such an element.

I suggest you write your pre-humans into the story in a way that does **not** elicit derision. If you are not confident you can pull it off, drop them.

I actually agree with sphennings that this is more of a writers SE question, but in brief you want to focus on integrating the pre-humans into the story. If you have an interesting story and the pre-humans integrate into it in a manner that adds value by making the story better and you do not get distracted into including all the non-story relevant details about the pre-humans, it should work out.

I'd start by making a list of what the pre-humans bring to the story and then looking into possible alternatives. This should give you good idea whether you actually need them or not.

If you do, you can then make another list of things about the pre-humans that do **not** add value to the story and figure out ways to either drop them or replace them with something that does add value.

In general, you do not really need to worry about **using** cliched elements in a story. Problems come from either including them without really using them or from the entire story being derivative and weak. In either case the cliched elements will get singled out as issues even though the problem is actually elsewhere.

But seriously, you can get a better answer to these issues in writers SE.

Worldbuilding is the place to ask about specific details of your pre-humans or their integration to your later society and story. There is overlap with writers that way too, but worldbuilding usually gives better answer to those types of questions.

Answer (score 8):

It should be alright as long as you the "Ancient Civilization" is interesting. The problem with the trope is that most authors 'Ancient Civilization" is boring.

One recommendation is not reveal all the lore surround the Ancient civilization to your character or readers. Instead yet your characters discover little bits about the Ancient civilization through out the story.

Comment: I would note that Brian Sanderson is a very successful writer and uses the "Ancient Civilization" in a number of his novels; among which the Mistborn serie which is an all-time favorite of mine, where a large part of the novel is *understanding* what happened in those ancient mythical times so as to solve today's problems.

Answer (score 2):

Making one up from scratch would elicit a groan from me because it's a whole bunch of stuff to learn and decide how it interacts yet doesn't have reuse value outside that tale, and I couldn't discuss it for instance with others without going into a bunch of background detail.

But building on existing pre-human societies wouldn't if you didn't twist things too far. The reason I say this is because many prehuman socities (legendary or religious or whatever) are fairly well known and/or easy to research and pick flaws if you have them. Every religion has a prehuman society of some sort or other, some have multiple. It's interesting to see someone build a coherent tale using them as a base concept for parts of it and it's a great read when they do it successfully and even better if they expand logically on the prehuman society in a believable way.

Comment: In its current form it would only take up a small part. If you have seen Man of Steel, the latest origin story for Superman, the very first Krypton scene would be a good analogy. I don't plan on getting bogged down in details, just want to let the readers know what it was like and what they did, and then its back off to the main story.

Comment: Seems a bit pointless having it if it isn't explored well. Movie is different from a book in that you can use snippets better. When I read, I settle down and either get lost in the book, or throw it away. And Superman has been around a long time, everyone knows about krypton and happy to learn more. It's not starting from scratch.

Comment: But to present a story and then dive into a past for 4 chapters is also unrealistic. If the history is worth exploring then I certainly will, but not at the cost of the main narrative (:

Comment: thats why it's better to either hardly touch it and leave it mysterious or build on one thta has been explored before and is widely known.